# Formula for incremental payment plan starting low and ending high

Tags: math

I think this is simple but maybe I'm over thinking it or I'm just crap at Math. 
I'm trying to work out a formula for a incremental payment plan calculator without interest, That starts with low payment and ends on the 8 month with higher payment.

```
$6,600 / 8 = $825 per month
```

The above is showing $825 per month for 8 months.
I want the first payment to start low and increment up per month until the last payment is higher until the 6,600 is payed.

how would I work this out in Math terms.

Comment: There are not enough details. How exactly you want the payment to grow over time? For now answer such as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6572` meets all your requirements but I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: what is 1,2,3 .... meant to be %

Comment: No. `$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $6572` are exactly 8 payments, starting low ($1) raising over time and ending high ($6572) and the sum is exactly $6600. This is a simple example to show that your current problem is not fully specified because that answer meets all current requirements. So you probaly have some other **_implicit_** requirements that you didn't put explicitly. Such as payments should be an arithmetic progression or geometric progression or some other way to specify unique answer.

Comment: No I mean I want to be a percentage of the total over time. Time meaning 8 months. so it would be smaller percent to pay the first month then increase over each month until the 8 month where the payment will be the largest payment. Over the 8 month span the total you would pay is 6,600

Comment: Eric, you seem to don't understand my concern. Obvsiously there is some rule that generates that sequence of payments. If you want it in percents here is another example `1%, 2%, 3%, 4%, 5%, 6%, 7%, 72%`. It is in percents, sum is 100%, it raises over time, etc. It still meets all your requirements. You **_have to specify_**  some **_more requirements_** to rule out this simple solution. So what are those additional requirements?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some sense you are underthinking it rather than overthinking it, since there are infinitely many solutions and you haven't given any criteria for choosing between those solutions.

Presumably you want the increments to be the same size each month.

Let `x` be the initial amount and `y` the monthly step size

You want

```
x + (x+y) + (x + 2y) + ... + (x + 7y) = 6600
```

or

```
8x + 28y = 6600
```

Mathematically, this equation has infinitely many solutions. If you specify that `x,y` are positive and that furthermore, `x` has at most 2 decimal places so as to be exactly expressible as currency, there are still a very large number of solutions.

What you can do is solve for `y` in terms of `x` to get that:

```
y = (1650 - 2x)/7
```

But -- you would still have to pick `x`. This formula would allow you to explore the trade-off between `x` and `y`. For example, if pick `x = 500` then `y` is (approximately) `92.86` (you would probably have to adjust the final payment by a few pennies to get it to balance out in the end).

Comment: John, although OP didn't answer to my requests to clarify requirements, I agree that arithmetic progression is the most probale thing he means. Still I think that starting with the mean (i.e. `x+3.5*y` in your notation and which should be 3300 anyway) provides more clear description of what happens and makes it easier to play with `y` which to me makes more sense. I mean defining the sequence as `3300 - 3.5*y`, `3300 - 2.5*y`, ..., `3300 + 3.5*y`

Comment: @SergGr That definitely makes sense but is partially a matter of taste. On the one hand the numbers in your approach are cleaner than the things like 7 in my approach. On the other hand, I find it more natural to think of the initial payment as the main parameter and then computing what the corresponding `y` is. I envisioned OP as doing something like setting up a spreadsheet and plugging in candidate `x` until they found an `x,y` pair that struck a nice balance.

Comment: John, I expect that usually the goal of having "good and round" `y` and thus having good values for all payment is more important then just having pre-defined starting point. But of course it might be otherwise.

Comment: @SergGr In my case I've periodically taught business math courses over the years in which we get into (among other things) the mathematics of loan amortization and how to set up amortization schedules. In such computations, payments that need to be rounded to the nearest penny with compensating changes to the last payment are the rule rather than the exception. Thus before I even began I was expecting the sort of phenomenon that happens with `x = 500`. It is nice how your approach gives a way of getting round numbers.

Comment: **_Bugfix_** just in case someone will read this discussion in the future, the **_mean_** in my first comment is obviously **_825_** = 6600 / 8, rather than 3300 as mentioned originally. Also you can get "nice and round" values for all payments if and only if the mean is itself "nice and round". Otherwise no `y` could fix all the payments values at the same time.